# Работа с окнами сторонних программ

Tags: pdf, delphi

Добрый день. Помогите, люди добрые!

Есть программа на Delphi, результаты работы она сохраняет в файл формата `pdf` (делается это с помощью `doPdf` из `MSWord`). Можно ли программно как-нибудь связаться с окном `doPdf`, которое запрашивает сохранение? А именно, чтобы программа не запрашивала имя сохраняемого файла, а делала это автоматически... Буду рада любому совету. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Элементарно. Необходимые функции WinAPI: FindWindow, Sleep, FindWindowEx, SendMessge.
Программа должна ждать появления окна doPDF, найти на нем дочернее окно с текстом OK, послать ему сообщение WM_CLICK

Comment: Я тоже их использую. Сначала я вызываю функцию PrintOut() далее FindWindow(). Дело в том, что вторая команда выполняется уже после того, как файл сохранился.

Comment: Печать идет из ворда или из программы на делфи?

Comment: Программно в delphi вызывается печать при этом в ворде документ переделывается в документ формата pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Если вызов печати синхронный, то другого решения как использовать дополнительный поток в голову не приходит.